# extract certain rows at nth + 16

Tags: r

I have a dataframe cbr. I want to extract row 17:27 and every next 16th row until row 16369 such that the extracted rows will be 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43  49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 .............16369. The idea that I have is that:

```
> 17:27
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
> 17:27
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
> 17:27 + 16
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
> 17:27 + 32
 [1] 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
> 17:27 + 48
 [1] 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
```

However, I think, my idea is cumbersome. I think it should be written in a simple code. Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want, because your desired output in the text of your question runs straight from 17 to 16369; there is no break every 16th row. However, what you have asked for is: 

c(17:27, seq(33, 16369, 16))

Comment: Your number will not neatly end at `16369`. The 16 multiple will end at `16043`.

Comment: Here's the closest you can get `c(mapply('+', list(17:27), 16*1:1001))`

Comment: Try this get the row indexes: `ix <- c(outer(17:27, seq(0, 16369, 16), "+")); ix <- ix[ix <= 16369]`

Comment: Thanks Pierre. What I want to do is to extract row numbers from a data frame. The row numbers are those generated already in this sequence (Map('+', list(17:27), 16*1:1001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a preview of the iteration:

```
Map('+', list(17:27), 16*1:4)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
```

We can continue this process further to reach the end goal:

```
Map('+', list(17:27), 16*1:1001)
# ...
# ...
#
# [[998]]
#  [1] 15985 15986 15987 15988 15989 15990 15991 15992 15993 15994 15995
# 
# [[999]]
#  [1] 16001 16002 16003 16004 16005 16006 16007 16008 16009 16010 16011
# 
# [[1000]]
#  [1] 16017 16018 16019 16020 16021 16022 16023 16024 16025 16026 16027
# 
# [[1001]]
#  [1] 16033 16034 16035 16036 16037 16038 16039 16040 16041 16042 16043
```